# Como inserir elemento dentro de outro criado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quando carrego a página, tenho algumas checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

E quando chegar no ready da página, quero colocar a checkbox dentro de uma label com class 'checkboxPersonalizada', ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
<label class="checkboxPersonalizada">
     <input type="checkbox">
     <i></i>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que possa utilizar o wrap do jquery para atingir o que deseja da sequinte forma.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var checkboxElment = $('#checkboxWrapped');
  var wrapper        = $('<label/>').addClass('checkboxPersonalizada').text();
  var extraElem      = $('<i/>').text();

  checkboxElment.wrap( wrapper ).parent().append( extraElem );
});
```

link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRyRJR

Deixei a propriedade text caso queira adicionar algo.

Comment: Deu certinho!!! Muuuuuuuuuuito obrigado!!! :D.. Nao conhecia o wrap..

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou muito claro sua pergunta. Mas seria algo do tipo?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var conteudo = $(".checkboxPersonalizada").html();
   var check = "<input type='checkbox'>";
   $(".checkboxPersonalizada").html(conteudo + check)
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkboxPersonalizada">
  oi
  <i></i>
</label>
```